# Symfony2 injecting entityManager error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am following a Doctrine ORM Symfony2 [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#book-doctrine-field-types). When it comes to Persisting Objects to the Database I get this error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "BooksApi\BookBundle\Controller\IndexController".
```

The only thing I am doing differently in my code is that I am trying to create EntityManager as a service....

services.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="booksapi.controller.index"
                 class="BooksApi\BookBundle\Controller\IndexController">
            <argument type="service" id="booksapi.repositories.test_repository" />
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

my Index Controller:

```
<?php

namespace BooksApi\BookBundle\Controller;

use BooksApi\BookBundle\Entity\BooksEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class IndexController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    public $em;

    /**
     *  @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager
    ){
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function testAction()
    {

        $book = new BooksEntity();
        $book->setTitle('Tomazi in da Jungle');
        $book->setPrice('19.99');
        $book->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

        $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $this->em->persist($book);
        $this->em->flush();

        return new Response('Created product id '.$book->getId());
    }
}
```

So looking at the error getDoctrine method is not recognised....any idea why...?
How can I fix this.

Comment: You are missing the obvious.  $this->em is set in your constructor so remove $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); and all will be well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ Quick solution:

Remove this line: `$this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`

2/ Better solution:

`IndexController` should extend `Controller`

(`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`)

And `getDoctrine` method could be available. By this way, Doctrine Entity Manager don't need to be injected. No constructor, no service definition.

Comment: Is there any way around than extending a Controller...?

Comment: ---> _Remove this line_: `$this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` <---

Comment: Yep, as you do: Injected Doctrine entity manager. So, use the first option I suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Defining your controller is a good practice so I would stick with that. Two things here seem wrong:

1. Your service definition (`services.xml`) contains two parameters and your Controller constructor accepts only one argument.
2. This line: `$this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` : you don't need it at all since your `$this->em` is already defined in constructor and its value is an `EntityManager` instance. Just remove this line and you should be good

And the reason you get this error is just because you are trying to use `getDoctrine` method which is a `Controller` method. What it [does](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L308) is just asking `Container` to create instance of `EntityManager` and since you have this instance already injected into `constructor` this call (`getDoctrine`) is not needed at all

Comment: Perfect this works. Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately Scoolnico answered first  so will accept his answer but up voted yours as well.